# Adding more info in InfoWindow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps-react

So I've been working with `google-maps-react` for a few months now and everything is working fine, now there is just a little thing that I don't understand. And that's probably why I can't achieve this.

So here is the structure of my `<InfoWindow>` :

```
<InfoWindow
    marker={this.state.activeMarker}
    visible={this.state.showingInfoWindow}
>
  <div>
      <h1>{this.state.selectedPlace.title}</h1>
   </div>
</InfoWindow>
```

So this is just fine and shows me the title, but I want some more information.

This is my `setState()` for that information, and the function that is triggered when I click on a `<Marker />` :

```
    onMarkerClick = (props, marker) => {
        this.setState({
            selectedPlace: props,
            activeMarker: marker,
            showingInfoWindow: true
        })
    }
```

I just call it like this :

`onClick={this.onMarkerClick}`

But here is a thing I don't get, where does those values (`props` and `marker`) come from? And how can I pass in another value in it? Let's say I want to pass in `m`, how do I do that? Because if I pass in `m` in the `onClick()` he says that `props` and `marker` are missing...

Please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I figured it out a little bit by analyzing how he got all the information.
I've seen that the value of `props` that is printed out in `onMarkerClick()` are all the props from the `<Marker />` itself, so I added a data `prop` with my value `m` in it.

This is what my `<Marker />` looks like now :

```
<Marker
  key={uuidv1()}
  position={{ lat: m.x, lng: m.y }}
  title={m.title}
  data={m}
  onClick={this.onMarkerClick}
/>
```

now in `onMarkerClick` I can simply do `props.data` and I can access all the information.